# File pointers for CSV files in python

Tags: python

I am currently reading csv files as below-

```
csvfile1=open('file1.csv','rt')
reader=csv.reader(csvfile1)
    for i in range(0,count):
        c=0         
        for row in reader:
            if c==0:
                c+=1
                continue
            if ((int(arr[i][0])==int(row[0])) and (int(arr[i][1])==int(row[1]))):
                ------
                ------
            else:
                break
```

For each iteration of i, I want to start from one previous position relative to the current position. How can I move the file pointer back in case of csv files?

**Edit**
When my inner loop breaks, the file pointer is already increased. For the next iteration, I want to recheck at the same position where I left off. So, I want to decrease the file pointer. I can do this using `lseek` for normal files but with `csv` files I have no idea how to decrease the file pointer.

Comment: What are you trying to archive with this?

Comment: See my edit..Basically, when my inner loop breaks, file pointer is already increased. For the next iteration, I want to recheck at the same position where I left off

Comment: No, i mean why is there an outer loop around the reader? It pretty much breaks it.

Comment: @Noober this feels like a typical [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. As Klaus said, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There IS an outer loop around the reader loop! And it should not be there. Also your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation. I have an array and I am checking the first two elements of the array with the first two elements of the row from the reader. If they match, I do something else, I break the reader and go to the next row of the array. So next time I will have to compare this new array elements with the row from the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rt'))
for row in reader:
    if row[:2] == arr[:2]:
        # your code
    else:
        # your other code
```

In case your array is 2D, meaning you have multiple lines to check put that inside the reader loop:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rt'))
for row in reader:
    for arr_row in arr:
        if arr_row[:2] == row[:2]:
            # your code
        else:
            # your other code
```